# Why can't Mathematica solve this differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

Consider:

```
DSolve[D[S[u,v],u,v]-w^2/4 S[u,v]==0,S,{u,v}]
```

Mathematica cannot solve this equation (not version 10 at least), but a solution is simply

```
Cos[(u-v)w/2]
```

How can I force Mathematica to find this solution?

Comment: Maple results in $$S \left( u,v \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{{\rm e}^{{\it \_c}_{{1}}u}}{\it 
\_C2}\,{{\rm e}^{1/4\,{\frac {{w}^{2}v}{{\it \_c}_{{1}}}}}}
 $$

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

Using separation of variables $S(u,v) = U(u)V(v)$ we have

$$
U'(u)V'(v)=\frac{w^2}{4}U(u)V(v)
$$

or

$$
\frac{U'(u)}{U(u)} = \frac{w^2}{4}\frac{V(v)}{V'(v)} = \lambda
$$

now solving each ODE

$$
U(u) = C_1e^{\lambda u},\ \ \ V(v) = C_2e^{\frac{w^2 v}{4\lambda}}
$$

and then

$$
S(u,v) = C_1e^{\lambda u}C_2e^{\frac{w^2 v}{4\lambda}}
$$

Note the presence of $\lambda$ in this solution.

Comment: I believe $S(u,v)=\int_{\mathcal C}d\lambda\, c(\lambda) e^{\lambda u} e^\frac{w^2 v}{4\lambda}$ is a more general solution. By the way, you could use mathematica starting from the 3rd line.

Comment: The statement of @yarchik is ungrounded and doubtful:  think of the origin belonging to the interior of $C$.